# React-router-dom not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been following along with [this video](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) on ReactTraining.com to set up react-router-dom in my app.

Seems like everything is set up as intended and yet when I click on the different `NavLink`s, the content of my app doesn't change for some reason.

If I stub `{Sky}` for any of other other components (`HQ` and `Settings`) in that first `Route` path, they render properly. I know that the files are loading in correctly. I'm not sure why the content isn't changing however.

In my `dependencies`, I have `"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",` installed.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import Sky from './sky';
import HQ from './hq';
import Settings from './settings';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <section className="main-content">
                    <div className="menu-bar">
                        <NavLink to='/'>
                            <span className="logo" />
                        </NavLink>

                        <div className="nav">
                            <NavLink to='/'>Sky</NavLink>
                            <NavLink to='/hq'>HQ</NavLink>
                            <NavLink to='/settings'>Settings</NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/' component={Sky} />
                        <Route path='/hq' component={HQ} />
                        <Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
                    </Switch>
                </section>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```

**Edit: Occasionally this 404 shows up in my console:**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

It's referring mostly to hq.js but sometimes to settings.js. Both are in the same directory as Sky which is loading in just fine

Both HQ and Settings are very simple files (replace HQ with Settings and you have the Settings file)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class HQ extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='hq'>
                <h1>Welcome to HQ</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HQ;
```

Comment: react-router-dom should be in your `dependencies` not in `devDepencies`

Comment: I've tried both, unsuccessfully

Comment: sorry - wrong q.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Switch` component chose the first one route, that matches the URL path. You have three routes to go: `/`, `/hq`, `/settings`. When you address to `/` `Switch` component looks at the first (upper) route in the list and checks if it matches criteria. So the first `/` route matches and we proceed to the 'Sky' comp.

Now when you address `/hq` `Switch` component looks at the first (upper) route as before. Does it match? **YES** The first route `/` matches `/hq` thats why we still on 'Sky' page.

To prevent such behavior use `exact` attribute on `Route` component. Like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Sky} />
  <Route exact path='/hq' component={HQ} />
  <Route exact path='/settings' component={Settings} />
</Switch>
```

**404** error probably about unexisted favicon icon...

Comment: Thanks GProst. Why would the favicon have anything to do with this?

Comment: It have nothing to do with your initial problem. I just assume that 404 error in console is because of favicon (maybe something else).

Comment: You only need `exact` on the `"/"` route it turns out.

Comment: True. I just prefer to define paths explicitly :P

Answer (score 2):

For the new version of react-router. you may face this issue.. if you wrap your routes within `BrowserRouter`

```
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<NewCounter />} />
            <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

this will solve the issue.. since `exact` does not work in the new version.

Answer (score 2):

In the new version (v6) of the react-router-dom the `Switch` component is replaced by the `Routes` element.

The `exact` attribute can now no longer be used.

The component attribute is now called the element attribute.

The syntax has changed a bit too. The element attribute accepts a component is JSX format.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Sky/>} />
    <Route path="/lab" element={<HQ/>} />
    <Route path="/setting" element={<Setting/>} />
    <Route
        path="*"
        element={<Navigate to="/" replace />}
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```